# Please resolve this error for me

Tags: c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(@"C:\Users\Raymond\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite17\XMLFile.xml"));
    Repeater1.DataSource= ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

I am getting error message:

> C:/Users/Raymond/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/WebSites/WebSite17/XMLFile.xml' **is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.**

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Remove `Server.MapPath` from the equation... You already have the full path...

Comment: This site is not about solving your problems, but *helping* solve you problems. As for now, the question is not answerable at all, since no relevant information given. Voting to close.

Comment: Added an approach to resolve your error along with some explanation. I encourage you to try to *understand* the problem rather than just get it resolved by somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception tells you: you are passing a physical path `c:\\`

but

Server.MapPath expects a virtual path `~/`

Comment: Thank you Emo now I have idea to resole this error.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `MapPath`:

```
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\Raymond\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite17\XMLFile.xml");
```

A *physical path* is an actual path on your disk, whereas a *virtual path* is a path within your web application. `MapPath` maps a virtual path to a physical path. As you already have a physical path, you do not need it here.

You would need it if the path were like `~/XMLFile.xml`:

```
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(@"~/XMLFile.xml");
```

`~` is your web application's home in virtual paths.

Comment: Thank you Matthias.. With your help I had resolved the error..